# How to set output folder for resource compiler

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, makefile

I am trying to use a resource file (*.rc) in a command line compiled application, using a make file. I discovered that even though the current directory was the output directory, and that cl seems to be building its object files to this output directory, that the rc compiler will only put its output .res file in the same location as the .rc file. How can I, with some flexibility, tell rc to put its output file in a different location without a manual 'move' operation?

i.e.:

This will put source.obj file in the (current) `c:\foo\bar\` directory:

```
c:\foo\bar>cl c:\foo\src\source.cpp
```

Whereas this will put a .res file in the `c:\foo\res\` directory:

```
c:\foo\bar>rc c:\foo\res\resource.rc
```

The main problem is it is awkward to find a way to have the make file script do the post-compile move of the res file. Is there a way to change the output folder?

Answer (score 0):

Probably an answer to your question:
[MSDN specs for RC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381041%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: That's the closest I've got but it doesn't work for files found using the search and accessed using the makefile $< variable.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you have some problems to construct a filename for an rc-running command, using $< (first prerequisite) variable?

Comment: Ideally I could set the output file folder for the rc command. Second best would be I could find the output file name (and path) from the rc command automatically and generate the full path to the current folder for that file name. Right now I have hard coded the output file name and path '-fo .\version.res' but it will use that file name for every rc file it finds.

Comment: U can use $(dir $<) for extracting the dirname, $(notdir $<) for the filename, and $(patsubst %.old,%.new,filename) for changing the file suffix.

Comment: Is it possible to cascade multiple instructions? I have attempted to use `.\$($(notdir $<), %.rc, %.res)` as the path to the current directory, of the input file name from the first prerequisite with the extension changed. It isn't happy with this, how could I bring all of this together?

Comment: I am trying to use your instructions to generate my compile command, this is where I have gotten to: `$(RC) /fo .\$(patsubst %.rc, %.res, $(notdir $<)) $<`. To me this should amount to running pattern substitution of the file extensions on the file name from `notdir` and putting it at the current build directory. This should yield the full command `rc.exe /fo .\resource.res c:\foo\res\resource.fc`. However nmake complains of a missing ')'. What am I missing about bracket counts in these instructions?

Answer (score 0):

This is the NMAKE line I have for resource compiler:

```
$(RC) -fo$@ $**
```

It puts the resource file where I direct it.

It seems, however, that the directory has to exist beforehand, or RC throws its hands up in the air in dismay.  Maybe I've misunderstood this problem, but I'm right about that, it's pretty lame behavior.  And in that case, depending on the order of execution, you may need a MKDIR command in your makefile.